# Deploying on Merge, not on Pull Request with Google Cloud Build

Tags: google-cloud-build

I have a cloudbuild.yaml file which contains deployment steps (which is working nicely), however I do not want to execute these steps on a pull request, just a merge to a particular branch. How do I make cloudbuild distinguish between pull requests and merges?

Comment: My understanding of Cloud Build is that doesn't trigger on pull requests? Documentation says: "Note: Whether based on branch commits or tag commits, builds are only triggered on pushes to the remote origin -- not on local changes, pre-submits, or pull requests."

Comment: the gihub integration definitely triggers builds on pull requests. But I also don't see a way to detect that in the build container. I created a docker image that just echoed out all the environment variables that were set, and to my dismay, there were none that indicated pull request, or any git relevant data :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a somewhat hacky solution. In the cloudbuild.yaml I have added the following:

```
substitutions:
    _DEPLOY: '0'
```

And in the cloudbuild console I have added the _DEPLOY substitution as '1`. Then in my build steps I can check the _DEPLOY flag like so:

```
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gsutil'
  entrypoint: 'bash'
  args:
      - '-c'
      - |
        if [ "${_DEPLOY}" -eq "1" ]; then echo 'hooray'; fi
```

The _DEPLOY flag is set when there is a push to my branch, but not during the github integration (e.g. PRs).

Comment: Are you using the GitHub integration or are you just using Triggers in google cloud build? Because the GitHub integration fires on every commit to the repo, right?

Comment: I am using both. Having said that you are correct, however the triggers will allow the deploy while the github integration won't.